# htaccess rewriterule 301 conflict

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I am trying to get 
http://www.mysite.com/cat/top/union-made

to forward to 
http://www.mysite.com/cat/top/union-made-in-usa

But it seems to be mixing with my dynamic rewrites and I get this: 
http://www.mysite.com/cat/top/union-made-in-usa/2?topic=union-made&pg=

Here are my current htaccess rules:

```
RewriteRule ^cat/top/union-made/ /cat/top/union-made-in-usa [R=301,L]

#Redirect dynamic pages to static links
RewriteRule ^cat/top/([a-z0-9_-]+)/?([a-z0-9_-]*) /cat/index.php?top=$1&pg=$2 [NC,L]
```

I thought the [L] would stop the double rule, but no. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have also tried changing the order of the rules, and that does not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

To preserve friendly URLs and prevent loops, use this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^cat/top/([a-z0-9_-]+)/?([a-z0-9_-]*) /cat/index.php?top=$1&pg=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I still get the same resulting url. The only change seems to be that the final redirect is no longer passing the URL parameters to the index page.

Answer (score 0):

This rule is fine:

```
RewriteRule ^cat/top/union-made/ /cat/top/union-made-in-usa [R=301,L]
```

But your old rule needs to be tweaked to handle the multiple path depth and exclude "union-made"

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !union-made
RewriteRule ^cat/top/([a-z0-9_-]+)/([a-z0-9_-]*) /cat/index.php?top=$1&pg=$2 [NC,L] 

# If the last bit of the path isn't there, you can handle it separately here:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !union-made
RewriteRule ^cat/top/([a-z0-9_-]+)/? /cat/index.php?top=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Same as the other fix suggested, I still get the same resulting url. The only change seems to be that the final redirect is no longer passing the URL parameters to the index page.

Comment: It seems like the [L] is being ignored on the first rule. Is there a setting that will cause that?

Comment: The `[L]` just says to stop the rewriting process in the current iteration. The rewrite engine will keep looping through the rules until the URI going in is the same after the rewrite engine. These rules do exactly as what you seem to want when I put them in a blank htaccess file on my test apache server

Comment: I think I figured out some of the problems. I was going to http://www.mysite.com/cat/top/union-made instead of http://www.mysite.com/cat/top/union-made/ . Adding the slash on the url makes your rules work, but I need it to work without the slash. If I remove the slash from the rule it causes a loop on the redirect.